# When an item belongs to Bob, is it Bob's item or Bobs item

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Should I use:

That is Bob's phone
He is Bob's student
Bob's car is red

or:

That is Bobs phone
He is Bobs student
Bob's car is red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current convention requires *Bob's* in all those examples.